# How to find a data frame in a list from its attribute value?

Tags: r

I have several data frames that each represent data in a given condition.

For instance, df.1 is data measured at temperature t1, df.2 at temperature t2, and so on.

I have set an attribute temperature for each data frame and stored all data frames in a list.

Now I want to retrieve the data frame for a given temperature.

So I have two questions:

- is the attribute/list approach the recommended one?
- is there an elegant way to retrieve the data frame for the appropriate temperature? I see a way with a for loop, but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Here is an example code:

```
x <- seq(0, 50, by = 0.1)
y1 <- sin(x)
y2 <- cos(x)
df.1 <- data.frame(time = x, value = y1)
attr(df.1, "Temperature") <- 20.0
df.2 <- data.frame(time = x, value = y2)
attr(df.2, "Temperature") <- 30.0

df.list <- list(df.1, df.2)

result <- NULL
for (df in df.list) {
  if (attr(df, "Temperature") == 20) {
    result <- df
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: Does it need to be a list of data.frames? Why not a single data.frame with a temp column?

Comment: I does not need to be a list. It's a list because I read each data frame in a different file (using a for loop), and building a list seemed the easiest way to do it. But that was the first of my two questions: is there a better/more efficient way to store my data?

Comment: Question: what is the cost (in terms of memory/efficiency) to add a temperature column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I chose JeremyS's solution: add a temperature column in the data frame.

```
x <- seq(0, 50, by = 0.1)
y1 <- sin(x)
y2 <- cos(x)
df.1 <- data.frame(time = x, value = y1, Temperature = 20.0)
df.2 <- data.frame(time = x, value = y2, Temperature = 30.0)

df.combined <- rbind(df.1, df.2)

result <- subset(df.combined, df.combined$Temperature == 20)
```

I don't really know what is the impact in terms of performance and memory cost, but R and ggplot seem to be designed for data frames rather than lists. Using a pure data frame approach thus seems the most convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to provide appropriate names to your list created, e.g.

```
names(df.list) <- c("t20", "t30")
```

This way, you can call out the appropriate table according to the names, e.g.

```
head(df.list[["t20"]])
  time      value
1  0.0 0.00000000
2  0.1 0.09983342
3  0.2 0.19866933
4  0.3 0.29552021
5  0.4 0.38941834
6  0.5 0.47942554

head(df.list[["t30"]])
  time     value
1  0.0 1.0000000
2  0.1 0.9950042
3  0.2 0.9800666
4  0.3 0.9553365
5  0.4 0.9210610
6  0.5 0.8775826
```